# Ensuring Thread Safety and Improving Performance for Displaying Dynamically Changing Data in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, multithreading, android-jetpack-compose

I have an application that involves multiple threads emitting strings and displaying them in a Jetpack Compose activity. However, the current implementation is causing performance problems and crashes due to thread safety issues. Here's the simplified code snippet:

```
val lines = mutableStateListOf<String>()
thread {
    var cpt = 0
    while (running) {
        Thread.sleep(10)
        lines.add("Line #" + (++cpt))
        if (lines.size > 1000) lines.removeRange(0, 100)
    }
}

LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    items(viewModel.lines) { line ->
        Text(line)
    }
}
```

This code is problematic in two major ways:

Thread Safety: The mutableStateListOf is not thread-safe, and concurrently modifying it from multiple threads can lead to crashes and unexpected behavior.

Performance: The approach of continuously adding and removing lines from the list, even with thread-safe modifications, is not efficient and can lead to unresponsiveness.

How can I address these issues?

Comment: use a StateFlow instead initialize inside a viewModel and collectAsStateWithLifecycle in the composable